# Server variables in outbound rules always show /jakarta/isapi_redirect.dll rather than actual path

Tags: url-rewriting, http-headers, iis-8, coldfusion-11, server-variables

I'm running ColdFusion 11 on Windows 2012/IIS8 and am trying to set up URL writing in IIS with an outbound rule to allow a server variable to be added if the URL matches a certain regular expression:

```
<outboundRules>
    <rule name="Add header for .ext files" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_The_Url" pattern="*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="\.ext$" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" value="{REQUEST_URI}" />
    </rule>
</outboundRules>
```

The rule was always matching the (negated) condition and added the header with a value of '/jakarta/isapi_redirect.dll' I've tried a number of other server variables, but can't find a single one which outputs the path instead of /jakarta/isapi_redirect.dll.

I believe this is something to to with the interaction between IIS and the ColdFusion connector, but can't find any advice on how to resolve this. Is there a way I can correctly get the URL relating to the request in this rule, or some other way I can add a response header only in certain cases?

Comment: Which update / hotfix version are you running on your CF11 installation?

Comment: This server runs Update 3 (11,0,03,292480). If you need any more information let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ONLY way I've been able to work around this, is to create an Inbound rule that saves the original `{REQUEST_URI}` value to a custom server variable called `HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL`. [This guide](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/setting-http-request-headers-and-iis-server-variables) shows how to do this.

NOTE: If you follow the guide and name the custom server variable `ORIGINAL_URL`, it WILL BE BLANK in your outbound rule. I guess the jakarta ISAPI filter will only forward server variables that begin with `HTTP_X`.